# Current source controlled by an external resistor (Inside an IC)

Tags: resistors, current-source

I would like to control an internal IC current using just an external resistor.

The typical schematic would be the following:
[image: Controlled current source]

However, this method has at least two disadvantages:

- For Vdd=3.3V, requires a huge resistor value.
- It is highly dependent on NMOS Vth

Does anyone have a solution that reduces the required resistors and it is less transistor dependent?
What is currently done inside ICs?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a BMR (Beta Multiplier Reference) circuit.

Comment: You haven't said what value the internal current is and what load is presented internally and over what supply range it needs to keep a constant value and, how constant should that value be. Missing vital details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have a solution that reduces the required resistors and it
> is less transistor dependent?

Umm, not sure if you can get any simpler than three components for a current mirror. There is literally no way to get a simpler current mirror then the one described. You might be able to switch to BJT's for the current mirror, but then you also have to deal with the voltage drop across Vce.

> What is currently done inside ICs?

The current mirror with bjt's or fets is usually the way it's done in IC's, because it's simple (three components) and small and easy to make. You will see these types of mirrors in many amplifier circuits also if they need a current mirror.

If you need something that is more precise, using an amplifier to provide negative feedback is a more complex circuit (and the tradeoff is complexity for precision)

[image]
Source: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/how-to-generate-current-sources-and-sinks-of-arbitrary-magnitude

[image]
Source: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/how-to-generate-current-sources-and-sinks-of-arbitrary-magnitude